# Monorepo pattern with GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, monorepo

We have a monorepo project which we have multiple libraries and services.

We like to execute CI process only when library changes are detected and run CI for every consumer of a changed library.

For instance, we have `lib_a` that uses `lib_b`, once `lib_b` is modified I like to execute both pipelines.

Is that possible?

Comment: What did you try so far? [`rules:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) may help

Comment: I sure tried it, the issue is that we are trying to make it work dynamically, i.e rules:changes should get a variable/list of services that are consuming it somehow